# No xauth program; cannot forward X11

Tags: ssh, x11, macos, xforwarding, xauth

I got the following error message when I use `ssh -v -Y`. The server OS is mojave. Does anybody know what is wrong?

```
debug1: No xauth program.
Warning: No xauth data; using fake authentication data for X11 forwarding.
debug1: Requesting X11 forwarding with authentication spoofing.
debug1: Sending environment.
debug1: Sending env LANG = en_US.UTF-8
debug1: Remote: No xauth program; cannot forward X11.
X11 forwarding request failed on channel 0
```

Comment: Do you have X11 installed on your MacOS system?

Comment: How to check it? I have this ```$ which xauth
/opt/X11/bin/xauth
```

Comment: `ssh server which xauth` shows nothing. How to add it to `$PATH`? If I login with ssh, it is there. The problem is how to let ssh know where xauth before I am fully logged in.

Answer (score 15):

Both your client and the server are complaining that they can't find the xauth program. The "debug1: No xauth program" message comes from your client, saying it can't find a copy of `xauth` locally. The "Remote: No xauth program; cannot forward X11" message is from the server, saying it can't find xauth either. The default location for both client and server is `/usr/X11R6/bin/xauth`, though your vendor could change it.

For the client, you can set the Xauth location in your [.ssh/config](https://man.openbsd.org/ssh_config#XAuthLocation):

```
XAuthLocation /some/path/to/xauth
```

For the server, you must set the location in the remote server's [sshd_config](https://man.openbsd.org/sshd_config#XAuthLocation):

```
XAuthLocation /opt/X11/bin/xauth
```

After modifying the config, you should run `sshd -t` to validate the config, then restart `sshd` to make it reread the file.

Answer (score 5):

I had to install xauth using dnf:

```
dnf install xauth
```

Then everything started working as expected.
For older Redhat systems use 'yum' instead of 'dnf' in the command above.

Comment: worked perfectly. Better with apt-get install xauth

Comment: Fedora/Red-Hat - `xorg-x11-xauth`

Comment: archlinux: pacman -S xorg-xauth   (if using kde this oackage got already installed in contrast to gnome)