# "debug1: No xauth program."

Tags: ssh

[No xauth program; cannot forward X11](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/552601/no-xauth-program-cannot-forward-x11)

I got the following error when tried the command.

```
$ ssh -v -X name@host
...
debug1: No xauth program.
Warning: No xauth data; using fake authentication data for X11 forwarding.
...
```

According to the above, I have the following line in /etc/ssh/sshd_config on the host already. Does anybody know how to fix this problem?

```
$ grep  XAuthLocation /etc/ssh/sshd_config
XAuthLocation /usr/bin/xauth
$ which xauth
/usr/bin/xauth
$ xauth version
1.1
```

Answer (score 0):

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39622173/cant-run-ssh-x-on-macos-sierra

The above answer is relevant. I am using Catalina. The following lines need to added in `/etc/ssh/ssh_config` under the Host * entry.

```
XAuthLocation /opt/X11/bin/xauth
ServerAliveInterval 60
ForwardX11Timeout 596h
```

Answer (score -1):

Install xauth on target host. Both sites have to have xauth installed to exchange/verify f.ex. MIT-MAGIC-COOKIE-1.

Comment: xauth is already installed on the target host.

Comment: Did you check more verbose diagnostic info like:
ssh -vvv host-addr

Comment: -vvv doesn't show anything useful in addition.

Comment: So you have  on both sides xauth installed. What do you have in ~/.ssh/config - maybe you have dedicated xauth there?
BTW debug3 should show you where xauth is looked for

Comment: I don't see any debug3 mentioning xauth other than the info that I showed in my original post. What debug3 info I should look for? ~/.ssh/config in my local machine has a set of hosts, but the one that I try to access is not there.